# Add span tags to link in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I add span tags to the following link?

```
<%= link_to 'demo', :action => 'test', :path => '' %>
```

Should display like this:

```
<a href="/test"><span>demo</span></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to '<span>demo</span>', :action => 'test', :path => '' %>
```

Comment: Oh I see. What about if its something like this? <% link_to h(filename), :action => 'test' %>

Comment: <%= link_to "<span>#{h(filename)}</span>", :action => 'test', :path => '' %>

Answer (score 7):

```
<% link_to :action => 'test', :path => '' do %>
  <span>demo</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The Rails API backs you up with their block example at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597

Answer (score 1):

or you can use link_to content_tag(:span, "demo"),:action => 'test', :path => ''